# How to build jQuery remove

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I have some like that.

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<table>
<tr title="test" id="ex1">
    <td><div class="move">Hello</div></td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr id="ex2">   
    <td><div class="move">Hello</div></td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>       
</table>

<button>Move</button>
<script>
$("button").click(function () {
    $(".move").remove();   
    });
</script>
```

If I press button, the both div's will moved. But I need to move only one, according to id of tr it laid.

I have only wrong ideas:

```
$(".move").parent.parent.attr('id', 'ex2').remove();
```

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That would be

```
$("#ex2 .move").remove();
```

Simple ya? remember that jQuery selectors are the same as CSS selectors.

Comment: I think this is actually the best answer, if only ex2 was a class and not an id? It should be $("#ex2 .move").remove();

Comment: Should it not be `$('#ex2 .move").remove()` as `ex2` is an id?

Answer (score 1):

You could simplify this.

```
$('.move').parents('tr').remove();
```

This will find the nearest parent that is also a `<tr>` and will remove it.

...wait. So you want to click a single button and then have it remove only the one div with that specific ID?

In that case just use

```
$('.move').parents('#ex2').remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this: - [jsFiffle](http://jsfiddle.net/FloydPink/2P47F/)

```
$(".move", "#ex2").remove();
```

What this does is selects the element(s) with css class of `move` within all the children elements (context) of the element with id `ex2` and then removes them.

Checfk this for more on the `jQuery(selector, context)` syntax - http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/

Answer (score 0):

You can use a more specific selector: http://jsfiddle.net/rWDnM/2/

```
<table>
<tr title="test" id="ex1">
    <td><div class="move">Hello</div></td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr id="ex2">   
    <td><div class="move">Hello2</div></td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>       
</table>

<button id="button1">Move</button>
<button id="button2">Move 2</button>
<script>
$("#button1").click(function () {
    $("#ex1 .move").remove();   
});

$("#button2").click(function () {
    $("#ex2 .move").remove();   
});
</script>
```